# Why using hexadecimal in computer is better than using octal?

Tags: comparison, computer-architecture, hexadecimal

What are benefits that hexadecimal provides? And is it really octal is less common than hexadecimal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I mean, the computer itself doesn't store any values in hexadecimal, it stores them as binary. However, we do choose to represent them as hexadecimal digits, for one main reason -- it's the easiest, most concise way to represent bytewise data:

```
0110 1011 becomes 6B in hex
```

Octal would require grouping of digits into 3, which would not allow for separation at byte level:

```
01 101 011 becomes 153 in octal
```

Note that the most significant digit will never be greater than 3.

Answer (score 3):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#In_computers):

> All modern computing platforms, however, use 16-, 32-, or 64-bit
>   words, further divided into eight-bit bytes. On such systems three
>   octal digits per byte would be required, with the most significant
>   octal digit representing two binary digits (plus one bit of the next
>   significant byte, if any). Octal representation of a 16-bit word
>   requires 6 digits, but the most significant octal digit represents
>   (quite inelegantly) only one bit (0 or 1). This representation offers
>   no way to easily read the most significant byte, because it's smeared
>   over four octal digits. Therefore, hexadecimal is more commonly used
>   in programming languages today, since two hexadecimal digits exactly
>   specify one byte.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, everything is stored in binary. Think; the IPv4-adress 192.168.0.1 in binary it would be 11000000.10100000.00000000.00000001. Imagine an IPv6-address written in binary. It would be unpractical.

Comment: As an aside, the dotted-decimal IP address `192.168.0.1` is the unsigned int `3232235521` which how it's actually stored (which translates into the binary you've posted, but without the dots).